# Session timeout Iframe

Tags: .net

On My aspx page in a Iframe I am showing a webpage from different server. When user is doing some set up on a website shown in IFRAME my app timeouts because of inactivity outside of Iframe. How do I avoid this if user is actively doing something in Iframe site? ( I want to avoid timeout only if user is actively doing something in Iframe)

thanks

Comment: Have a small javascript "heartbeat" script ping your server on a fixed schedule, to keep the session alive.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a tough one but I have a solution that works.  It's called "Cross Domain Scripting" and you should Google that for more info.  I used this approach when integrating ads into [SocialNetwork.com](http://www.socialnetwork.com) because the javascript and ads are from a different domain name.  Anyway, this technique can be applied here to solve your problem.

When you are in an iFrame you can communicate with the parent frame using JavaScript.  What you do, is make javascript in iFrame add a # to the end of your URL like this:

myurlformyiframe.com/mypage/#nonce00000001

Then when something happens in the iFrame, change that URL to something else like:
myurlformyiframe.com/mypage/#nonce00000002

When you change the URL after the hash (#) using javascript it doesn't cause a page refresh.

THEN what you do is in the parent window, you hook a javascript event on to the iframe to notify you when the URL in the iframe changes.  Whenever that happens, do an ajax postback (I recommend use jquery) to your server that you want to protect the session for.

This way, the activity happening in the iframe can trigger hits from the main / outer frame against your server to preserve the session.

Here's a great library that makes it very easy to pass messages between iFrames and a parent window:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html

With the jquery plugin you can make a script like this in the outer page:
 $.receiveMessage(
        function (e) {
            procResp(spanID, e.data);
        },
        'myurlformyiframe.com/mypage/'
        );

There's also a $.postMessage function that goes inside the iFrame. So you call the post message function and send ANYTHING whenever your trigger event, a click, timer whatever, happens inside that iframe.  That causes procResp to get fired in the outer part of your page, the parent of the iFrame, which can make an ajax hit to your server to preserve session.

When the "message" is received by changing the URL after the # that data will be passed by e.data into your procResp javascript function.

Comment: I forgot to mention one more thing I am posting a form to different URL and Target of form is Iframe so I am not direclty specifying SRC property of Iframe. Will you solution work in this situation?

Comment: Your comment isn't clear - you can't post to an iframe, you have to post to a URL.  Please explain in a more specific way or include a link to more details.  I suspect still, that the approach I describe will help you. You should read up on it and try it!

Comment: I am posting following form on button click and target of form is a IFRAME ( where response of form post is shown , which is another website)     <form id="frmSSO" action='<%=formAction%>' method="post" name="frmSSO" target='iframe1'  >
        <input type="hidden" name="TARGET" value='<% = formTarget%>' />
        <input type="hidden" name="Encoding" value="B64" />
        <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value='<% = resp%>' />              
    </form>

Comment: You could have your button call javascript, which posts a message to your iframe as per the method i already described, and then handle that event in the target frame to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation. I am using an IFrame to open a payment gateway url and till the payment is complete (sending the request of the payment and getting a confirmation number for the same) I cannot do anything with my app. 
But in this case, I have set a timeout value for the iframe url of 30 secs, SO if I do not get any response from the third party service I show it as timeout. And in this case, my app doesn't hangs up as 30secs is a pretty less time. 
Not sure if your problem is something similar. If yes, you can try out having a threshold limit of the url in the iframe being active.

Comment: No My Situation is little different - I open the other site in Iframe, where he will do his phone registration and stuff he can be there on that site from 0 mins to any mins doing his registration. my app timeouts after 10 mins if it's inactvie. I am not sure how to do this in my situation?